# Show additional attributes in related products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I'm trying to show additional attributes for products that are showing up in the "Related Products" section of an individual product listing. I have some items that have `Artist/Author` attributes and if they do I would like to show them.

Here is part of my code in: `template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
  <div>
    <div class="product panel" data-equalizer-watch>
      <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(280) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
      <div class="product-details">
        <h6 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h6>

        <?php if ($_item->getAuthorArtist()): ?>
          <span class="author">By: <?php echo $_item->getAuthorArtist() ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

For some reason the author/artist never show up. I can verify that the author/artist is correctly configured because I'm using very similar syntax (changing `$_item`) on the main product page and it's working fine.

I found this question: [show attributes in description.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45704/show-attributes-in-description-phtml) but when I tried editing it like this `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('AuthorArtist'); ?>` it makes Magento blow up.

Somehow I'm must not be targeting the item object correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always like using `$_item->getData("attribute_code")`.  It's just cleaner and I quickly know when I am accessing an attribute or when I'm calling a procedure.

Go to your Magento Admin, and visit the page `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`.  Choose the attribute you have setup for Artist/Author.  Note the "attribute code" and use it in the getData call I show above.  Also, while you are here, make sure `Used in Product Listing` is set to true.

Comment: getData for the win

Comment: I knew that I had to enable the attribute in the Magento Admin... but somehow I missed that! Thanks for the help! Thanks for the info about `getData` , that's good to know.